# Return class that has static member through rest api

Tags: java, static

I have a class with static variable

```
@Data
public final class Code {
    private static Map<String, List<String>> codesForType = new HashMap<String, List<String>>() {{
        put("code1", Arrays.asList("AVDF", "WREQ", "AWER"));
        put("code2", Arrays.asList("SHYT", "DWEA", "XSSS", "AQWE"));
      
    }};

    public static List<String> getCodesByType(String type) {
        return codesForType.get(type);
    }
}
```

with following api

```
@GetMapping("/codes")
    public Code getCodeForType() {
        return new Code();
    }
```

This is giving exception with message `No converter found for return value of type: class com.model.Code`.

Tried making the member as public but still has the same issue.
It works when I remove static keyword from `private static Map<String, List<String>> codesForType`

I could be missing a basic understanding of static keyword.

Comment: Tipp (Nothing to do with your question): You should try to avoid this initialization technique because it creates an anonymous additional class every time you use it, and also contains hidden references to the enclosing object and could cause memory leak problems. - See "codesForType"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new object as your methods are static.

you can simply do this :

```
@GetMapping("/codes")
    public List<String> getCodeForType() {
        // replace type with something you will receive in your request.
        return Code.getCodesByType(type);
    }
```

Comment: I want to return the Code object not list of types based on code. My api response should look like this ```{
    "codesForType": {
        "code1": [
            "AVDF",
            "WREQ",
            "AWER"
        ],
        "code2": [
            "SHYT",
            "DWEA",
            "XSSS",
           "AQWE"
        ]
}```